# Options for a functional-style enthusiast?

Tags: c#, unity, functional

Senior programmer who has been coding in a functional style for years. I want to make an attempt on the indie games market, but I don't find any good, big platform that provides a good way to code using a functional style. And the fact Unity3D pretty much domains that market, I'm pretty much limited to C#. I wonder if there is another way?

Comment: Is there no OpenGL setup in .NET that you could use F# with?

Comment: Also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/what-functional-language-is-most-suited-to-create-games-with?rq=1 as further material.

Comment: Also also, 1.7 seconds of Googling: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Game_Development.  Probably linked in one or both of those GDSE articles I linked.

Answer (score 0):

F# works as well as C# with libraries like OpenTK and XNA.

I have not used Unity, but it seems that you can import external dlls into Unity, so you could write your core logic in F# dlls and use those classes from within Unity as well.

Answer (score -1):

What about [OpenGL for Haskell?](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Opengl)

Comment: This is better suited as a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @VaughanHilts It's not critique nor clarification request. It is an answer; it is an option for functional programmer who wants to create games.

Comment: While it does provide an answer to the question, it only does so because it was a bad question that solicits these types of answers. And answering such questions promotes them as OK, since the OP still gets what they want, at the expense of the quality of the site.

Answer (score -2):

What about using JavaScript, there are quite a few JavaScript Game engines out there.
And Javascript is functional.

Comment: JavaScript can be used in a functional-ish manner, but is no more functional than C# is at its core; the opposite, in fact.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch I wouldn't be so quick to say so. Function objects pervade most JS api's. The fact that JS _provides_ function objects is a pretty big step. [See this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962604/is-javascript-a-functional-programming-language).

Comment: @bobobobo Also Java 8 brings functional programming to procedural language, but it won't be an option for functional programmer.